# AES Encryption and Decryption of data

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption

I am developing an iOS app in which:
I am calling a **Java** web service.

The service sends me the following data :

1. Salt value (Base64 encoded)
2. Base64 encoded key
3. Encrypted data

Now I need to decode this key and use it for the decryption of the same data.

> The problem with me is when I try to decode the key I get nil
>   `NSString`.

Here by is the code that I have been trying :

```
NSData *cipherKeyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"W0JAM2IwMDVhYmM=" options:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *strKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cipherKeyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hence, I am not able to decrypt the data.
Can anyone please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First `strKey` is a string: "[B@3b005abc", I do not get `nil`.

Keys are generally data, `cipherKeyData` is the key. The reason the key was supplied in Base64 is because the actual key is data, not a string.  No further conversion to a string is necessary. The key parameter to the Common Crypto encryption functions are data, not an `NSString`.

Not all data can be converted to a string, there are data bytes and for UTF-* sequences that are illegal code points. In the case in the question the data will convert to the string "[B@3b005abc".